# Solutions of a PDE problem given in the Riemann invariant diagonal form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, cauchy-problem

First, let's say we have a Cauchy problem:

$$ 
(1) \hspace{0.5cm} u_t (x,t)+ div f(u(x,t))=0,
$$

where the initial condition is given with $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$, $x \in A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d, d \geq 1$, $t \in [0,T]$ and $u \in  \mathbb{R}^n, n \geq 1$.

If this system is endowed with *the coordinate system of Riemann invariants*, we could write it as **a diagonal system** where the new variables are Riemann invariants

$$ 
(2) \hspace{0.5cm} s_t (x,t)+ D(s) \cdot  s_x(x,t)=0,
$$

with initial condition $s_0(x)$ and a diagonal matrix $D(s)$.

And let's take a special kind of initial conditions (called *Riemann*):

$$(3) \hspace{0.5cm} (u)(x,0)= \begin{cases}
 u_l, x<0 \\[2ex]
 u_r, x\geq 0,
\end{cases}$$

i.e. in the Riemann invariants form:

$$(4) \hspace{0.5cm} (s)(x,0)= \begin{cases}
 s_l, x<0 \\[2ex]
 s_r, x\geq 0,
\end{cases}$$

where $u_l$, $u_r$, $s_l$, $s_r$ are constants. From the literature, depending of the concrete system, we know that the solution of $(1),(3)$ consists of shock waves, rarefaction waves and contact discontinuities. This solution is *weak solution* in the PDE sense.

**But what could we say about the solutions of system $(2),(4)$**?

Things I know (probably):

- System (2) is not given in the conservative form so we do not have weak solutions in the PDE sense.
- On the other hand, if we know the shocks, rarefactions and contact discontinuities from $(1),(3)$, we could change variables from $u$ to $s$ and get the shocks, rarefactions and contact discontinuities given in the Riemann invariants $s$. But I think that those are not the weak solutions of $(2),(4)$ then.
- If we instead of $(3)-(4)$ have smooth initial conditions, then if we know the strong PDE solutions of $(1)$, we know the strong PDE solutions of $(2)$. But we do not know nothing about the connection between weak solutions of the two problems.

**Could we say anything else about solutions of the systems?  And are there some other kind of solutions?**

**I am trying to understand why the system given in Riemann invariants is so important.** The only thing I have found so far is that in the system of Riemann invariants rarefaction waves are streight lines parallel to the coordinate axis (page 313 of [[Dafermos book]](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662494493)). This is nice, but I hope it is not all.

Answer (score 4):

The Riemann invariant form is mostly important for computing classical solutions such as rarefaction waves and simple waves, along which one Riemann invariant is constant. Rewriting the original problem in the Riemann invariant does not prevent to use the method of characteristics. For instance, this technique can be successfully applied to solve this [typical problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2514681/418542). For shocks and contact discontinuities, the solution follows Hugoniot loci. That is to say, a weak solution must satisfy the Rankine-Hugoniot conditions. There is no big advantage of working with Riemann invariants in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. This is all true but I have a (maybe wrong) impression that there is more. For example Chapter 12 of the same book titled "Genuinely nonlinear systems of two conservation laws" deals with more than just rarefactions, and almost whole is given in Riemann invariants.

Comment: Thank you. It is nice to see some additional application of the Riemann invariants. In that post all the solutions are strong in the PDE sense (all the derivatives exist). Could we say something about weak solutions in the PDE sense (think in the terms of shock wave, rarefaction and contact discontinuity) or in some other sense besides strong?

Comment: Thanks again. Also I am not sure you can check it because the system  in the Riemann invariants form is not given in the divergent form (it is in the quasilinear form). And we can check Rankine-Hugoniot jump conditions only from the diagonal form (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @Mark Yes, makes sense.