# Solving Nonlinear Wave Equation $u_{tt}=a(e^{\lambda u}u_x)_x$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, wave-equation

Salutations, I have been trying to solve this nonlinear wave equation that is a partial differential equation of the form (just for academical curiosity):
$$u_{tt}=a(e^{\lambda u}u_x)_x$$
As I read in this document ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UbgdP41Mqa3FdsFFKH6DoEYQxlcxeAFZ/view?usp=sharing)) (page 3, equation No. 7), it can be solved using this form of solution:
$$
\begin{align}
u(x,t) & =\phi(x)+\psi(t)\\ & \Updownarrow \\
u_{tt} & =\psi_{tt} \\ 
u_x & =\phi_x
\end{align}$$
Then, replacing in non-linear PDE, I got this procedure:
$$
\begin{split}
\psi_{tt} & = a[e^{\lambda\left(\phi+\psi\right)}\phi_x]_x \\
& =a\left(e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)e^\left(\lambda\psi\right)\phi_x\right)_x \\
&=ae^\left(\lambda\psi\right)\left(e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)\phi_x\right)_x \\
& \Updownarrow \\  
\frac{1}{e^\left(\lambda\psi\right)}\psi_{tt} &=a\left(e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)\phi_x\right)_x  =m
\end{split}$$
The previous procedure led to the following equations:
$$
\begin{align}
a\left(e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)\phi_x\right)_x &=m \label{1}\tag{1}\\ \psi_{tt} &=me^\left(\lambda\psi\right)\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Approaching equation \eqref{1}, I got this procedure:
$$
\begin{split}
a\left(e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)\phi_x\right)_x=m \implies 
\int a\left(e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)\phi_x\right)_x \,dx & = \int \frac{m}{a} \,dx\\ 
e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)\phi_x & =\frac{mx}{a}+c_1\\ 
\int e^\left(\lambda\phi\right) \,d\phi &= \int \left(\frac{mx}{a}+c_1\right) \,dx \\ 
\frac{1}{\lambda}e^\left(\lambda\phi\right)&=\frac{m}{2a}x^2+c_1x+c_2
\end{split}
$$
Finally,
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln\left(\frac{\lambda m}{2a}x^2+\lambda c_1x+\lambda c_2\right)$$

Next, when I approached equation \eqref{2}, I got this procedure:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} &= me^\left(\lambda\psi\right) \\ 
\int \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} \frac{d\psi}{dt} \,dt &=m\int e^\left(\lambda\psi\right) \frac{d\psi}{dt}\,dt\\ 
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2 &= me^\left(\lambda\psi\right)+c 
\end{split}
$$
Then,
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2me^\left(\lambda\psi\right)+c_1}}\,d\psi = t+k 
$$
I´ve taken trigonometric substitutions and even I´ve used the hyperbolic inverse function and I´ve got these results for integral in left side:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{-2}{\lambda\sqrt{c_1}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{c_1} + \sqrt{2me^\left(\lambda\psi\right)+c_1}}{\sqrt{2c_1-2me^\left(\lambda*\psi\right)}}\right)\label{I}\tag{I}&\\
\frac{-2}{\lambda\sqrt{2me^\left(\lambda\psi\right)+c_1}} & \label{II}\tag{II} \\ \frac{-1}{\lambda\sqrt c_1}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{c_1} +w}{\sqrt{c_1} -w}\right)&\text{ where }w=\sqrt{2me^\left(\lambda\psi\right)+c_1}\label{3}\tag{II}
\end{align}
$$

I require help for finding the solution to equation $(2)$ because none of possible solutions guide to exact solution shown in this paper in spanish ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XXII8z2wK944tHZZ9KwdyspMztJ0-p85/view?usp=sharing)) (page 3, section 2).

I would be very thankful with any guidance or starting steps and/or explanations to find the correct procedure and exact solution.

Thanks for your time and your attention.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you can pull $e^{( \lambda \phi)}$ out of the derivative when it is dependent upon $x$. I think you meant to pull the $e^{(\lambda \psi)}$ term out instead? This may be a typo.

Comment: It can be solved by following the steps in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2514681)

Comment: @DaveNine thanks for letting me know about my typo, I didn´t realized it. I edited it.